# Uploading file with selenium Virustotal

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm trying to upload my file to upload in VirusTotal with selenium,But it keeps getting me this Error

```
Message: Unable to locate element: [id="fileSelector"]
```

This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='my_path')
        driver.get('https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload')
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/vt-virustotal-app//div[2]/vt-auth-checker/home-view//div/div[1]/vt-ui-selector/div[1]/vt-ui-main-upload-form//div/vt-ui-button[1]').click()
```

I also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('fileSelector').click()
```

and:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fileSelector"main"]').click()
```

I have to mention that first I want to make sure that I can locate the parameter so I used click().